# What are the different context for WORK?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Work = Force * Distance

I know that if you push an object 10 meters with a force of 50N, work would equal 500 J. That’s one way to utilize the work formula.

But I found out that the work formula can also apply to levers, but in the case of the levers, you don’t move an object horizontally. The distance refers to the distance between the effort force or resistant force and the fulcrum. 
I don’t understand why the work formula applies to the lever if you don’t displace anything.

Comment: Why can’t levers move an object horizontally? I have used a bar (lever) to move a machine along a floor...

Answer (score 2):

Work is sometimes explained very vaguely in introductory physics. This is a shame, since the work-energy theorem comes in very useful in classical mechanics. To state it simply, all the work-energy theorem states is that the amount of work done on an object is the change in energy of the object. The change in energy can be the change in the kinetic energy of the object or the change in potential energy or any other type of energy.

In the case of a lever, you are doing work on an object since you're changing its potential energy. You're changing the object's gravitational potential energy (by changing its height off of the ground). I don't know if you've done any calculus yet, but this integral is very useful for determining potential energy:

$$
U(x)=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}F(x)dx
$$
All this says is that the potential can be defined by a force (which is a function of distance) and a displacement. When you're changing the horizontal displacement of the object and doing work, you're defining a horizontal displacement as doing work. When you're talking about gravitational potential energy, you're defining vertical displacement as doing work. They're just different ways of defining the axes and the rules.

Hope that helped! (If anyone found something wrong in something I said, please let me know. I'd be happy to discuss about it and modify my answer where necessary)
.

Comment: When you apply work on an object, you change its displacement (horizontally or vertically) Is that what you're saying in simple terms?

Comment: Not necessarily. Say that something is already moving and you cause it to slow down or speed up, then you've done work. You've changed the kinetic energy of the object, which means a non-zero work was done. Don't just think about it in terms of displacement, but in terms of changes in energy in some way or another from what you define as the origin. The change in displacement only applies to specific circumstances, so it is better to think about it in the more general sense of changes in energy because you can solve more general problems this way.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. I was just thinking and I realize that wouldn't it make more sense if the work formula for levers was force * vertical distance?

Answer (score 1):

The work done for a point mass between points A and B is

$$ W = \int_A^B \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{x}. $$

Now let's use this to determine the formula for work done by a rotation. For simplicity sake, let's say we are rotating a lever arm of length $R$ which has nearly all the mass concentrated at the end (so that the moment of inertia is $\sim mR^2$).

Let's say we rotate with constant force. The lever's length is constant, so all of the displacement is angular. In terms of unit vectors, the displacement is in the $\hat\theta$ direction.

All considered, we have
$$ W = \int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{x} = \int \vec{F} \cdot (rd\theta)\hat\theta = \int (Fr)d\theta = \int \tau d\theta,$$
where $\tau$ is the torque exerted on the lever.

For extra clarity, note that $\vec{F} \cdot \hat\theta = F$ since the magnitude of $\hat\theta$ is unity, and because $\vec{F}$ and $\hat\theta$ are parallel.